# Visual Studio ASP.NET - Password is not hidden and it shows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hello i can't figure out why when logging and typing my password it is not hidden and the password is visible when typing. I've tried everything and cannot find a solution. I am also using sql server management alongside visual studio.

```
<div class="form-horizontal">

    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.username, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.username, new { @class="form-control"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.username)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.password, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's the markup?

Comment: @hardkoded HTML

Comment: I think what @hardkoded means is what does your markup look like? This is server-side code that you've posted here, not what gets shown on the client-side. You should [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: if you are using  input tag...then include type="password" attribute in that

Comment: You appear to be storing your passwords in clear text. Please don't do that, there are better ways.

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting to specifically use an html helper text box and mask the text. This is done using a "password" type tag. I went ahead and fixed your code.

Try replacing your code with this:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">

<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.username, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.username, new { @class="form-control"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.username)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.password, new { @class = "form-control" , @type="password"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password)
    </div>
</div>
```

All that I changed was in this line of code :

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.username, new { @class="form-control", @type="password"})
```

I added the `@type="password"`

The reason is that you want you make the type of your text box to be a password text box that way it masks the password.

Here is a [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_password.asp) link that shows you how to do this with an input tag.

Also you could use MvcHtmlString Html.Password.

That would look like this:

```
MvcHtmlString Html.Password(string name, object value, object htmlAttributes)
```

> The Html.Password() method generates a input password element with
>   specified name, value and html attributes.

**Example: Student Model**

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Name")]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool isNewlyEnrolled { get; set; }
    public string OnlinePassword { get; set; }
}
```

**Example: Html.Password() in Razor View**

```
@model Student

@Html.Password("OnlinePassword")
```

[Here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-password-passwordfor) is a great resource for the Html.Password() method .

Comment: There's also just `@Html.PasswordFor(...)`. Also, you edited the username textbox, not the password one.

Comment: Thanks codeCaster I'll include this as well.

Comment: Lol thanks for noticing that I put that in the wrong spot I fixed that too.